# Determine if a directory is empty, delete it if it is and delete that directory name from a separate list

Tags: shell, directory, csh

I have a directory named STA. Within that directory are about 600 other directories that have the format hh:mm:ss (for example 00:01:34). Within each of these sub-directories should be three files. I also have a file, 'waveformlist', (contained within STA) which is a list of all of these sub-directories i.e.:

```
00:01:34
00:02:35
etc.
```

A lot of the sub-directories do not contain these three files and are instead empty. I want to run a C-shell script to go through every sub directory and check if it is empty.
If it is empty I want to delete that sub directory from the main directory STA, and also remove that sub-directory name from the list 'waveformlist'.

Below is my script so far. It does not recognize when the sub-directory is empty or not and does not like the rm $dir line. Also, I do not know how to go and remove the sub-directory name from 'waveformlist'.

```
#!/bin/csh

echo "Enter name of station folder to apply filter to as 'STA' e.g. APZ:"
set ans = $<
cd $ans

set c=0

foreach dir (*:*)
    if ("${c}" == 0) then
    echo "Empty directory:" $dir
    rm $dir
    else
    echo ${dir} "has files"
    endif
end
```

I hope I have been clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

Normally I just use rmdir * because it will only delete empty directories, and will ignore directories that contain files, and normal files. You may get some errors, if you give it a directory with files or normal files. So it's a very safe command to execute.

Having said that, Something like this might be useful to you

```
foreach d ( $ans/* )
    if -d $d then
#        echo $d is a directory                                                                                                                                         
        set numfiles = ( `ls $d| wc -l` )
        if ( $numfiles == 0 ) then
            echo rmdir $d
            rmdir $d
        endif
    endif
end
```